# Passing argument in a .py script for nrpe plugin

Tags: centos, centos6, nagios, nrpe

Machine A = nagios master, Machine B = edge machine.

In machine A's host.cfg I have:

```
define command {
        command_name    check_tok
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_tok 123
}

define service
        use bg-service
        hostgroup_name  test_oob1
        service_description Recall12
        check_command   check_tok
        servicegroups   nrpe
}
```

In Machine B's commands.cfg in /etc/nrpe.d I have:

`command[check_tok]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.sh`

In machine's B's /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins, I have check_test.py and check_test.sh.

check.test.sh looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.py
exit $?
```

and check_test.py looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
        if sys.argv == '123'
            print("this ok")
            sys.exit(0)
        else: 
            print('this is not 123')
            sys.exit(2)
```

In machine's B /etc/sudoers.d/nrpe
`nrpe   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.py`

As you can see, the argument i am pasting to check_test.py is '123' and it should result in a sys.exit(0). however, in my nagios mon it said "  NRPE: Unable to read output "

Comment: Change `command[check_tok]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test` to `command[check_tok]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.sh`.

Comment: Oh, i did a typo in the post, I did actually made that change. It's till doesn't work tho.

Answer (score 2):

By default nrpe doesn't allow arguments. You may bypass this by setting `dont_blame_nrpe=1` in nrpe configuration. Also your nrpe must be built with `--enable-command-args`. However please note that:

```
*** ENABLING THIS OPTION IS A SECURITY RISK! ***
```

That being said, you really should hardcode your arguments to nrpe command in client side.

Also you must pass arguments from your shell script to python interpreter. Adding `"$@"` should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.py "$@"
exit $?
```

And `sys.argv` in your python script is a list, so you should write `sys.argv[1]` instead.

I suggest you first test your scripts locally before trying to connect from nagios side.

Comment: yea i tested my script locally already, there are some typoes in the post, thanks tho.,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-a` to pass args to NRPE.

Also, make the `-c` command call `$ARG1$` so you don't have to write a separate command object for every different NRPE call.

For example:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nrpe_arg
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}
```

and the service def:

```
define service {
    use bg-service
    hostgroup_name  test_oob1
    service_description Recall12
    check_command   check_nrpe_arg!check_tok!123
    servicegroups   nrpe
}
```

You also need the command on the NRPE daemon side to do something with the argument (It doesn't just magically get it):

```
command[check_tok]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_test.sh $ARG1$
```

You would then have a separate `check_nrpe` for calls that don't take any arguments, without the `-a $ARG2$1` on the end. (This is a similar concept as the commands in Debian/Ubuntu packages, except the other way around.)